# Programing the Nth discrete Fourier transform type error

Tags: python-3.x, complex-numbers

I am trying to define the following matrix through a function

```
import numpy as np
import cmath
def DFT(N):
w=cmath.exp((2j*math.pi)/N)
F=np.ones((N,N))
for i in range(1,len(F)-1):
    for j in range(1,len(F)-1):
        F[i,j]=w**(i*j)
return F
```

I continue to receive the error

```
File "<pyshell#6>", line 6, in DFT
F[i,j]=pow(w,(i*j))
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

and have tried the following

```
F[i,j]=pow(w,(i*j))

F[i,j]=w**(i*j)
```

I am unsure of what could be causing the error and have also redefined `w` similarly to how I redefined `F[i,j]` to try and see if that was the cause. I imagine the error comes from the fact that we get a real number for even powers, but to my understanding it should just return the number with a real and a 0j for the imaginary part. This is my first post and I'm still new to python, so I apologize if the posing of my question isn't done well.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue was in my matrix dtype, I fixed the problem by defining

```
 F=np.zeros((N,N),complex)
```